# how to create loop in R which automatically changes the date of my data set by annual interval and combines them all together in one data set?

Tags: loops, dplyr

Please, help me to create a loop to make it easier for the process below. Imagine I will need to go back at least 30 years.

```
library(lubridate)
m1y <- df %>% mutate(timestamp= timestamp-years(1)) %>% mutate(changes="-1y")
m2y <- df %>% mutate(timestamp= timestamp-years(2)) %>% mutate(changes="-2y")
m3y <- df %>% mutate(timestamp= timestamp-years(3)) %>% mutate(changes="-3y")
m4y <- df %>% mutate(timestamp= timestamp-years(4)) %>% mutate(changes="-4y")
m5y <- df %>% mutate(timestamp= timestamp-years(5)) %>% mutate(changes="-5y")
actual <- df %>% mutate(changes="0")
p1y <- df %>% mutate(timestamp= timestamp+years(1)) %>% mutate(changes="+1y")
p2y <- df %>% mutate(timestamp= timestamp+years(2)) %>% mutate(changes="+2y")

data <- rbind(m1y, m2y, m3y, m4y, m5y, actual, p1y, p2y)
```

This is example of data:

```
structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1479118194, 1479116870, 
1479113506, 1479113046, 1479112331, 1479111645, 1479111119, 1479110437, 
1479106612, 1479106218, 1479105192), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), heading = c(44L, 72L, 37L, 34L, 14L, 12L, 
15L, 13L, 45L, 14L, 16L), ground.speed1 = c(0.0830056886417697, 
0.0362715909791526, 0.373922822992792, 0.00365221791296628, 0.0486211951021842, 
0.181217669168713, 0.0550965979273319, 0.154570465194361, 1.55730089114108, 
0.259570141800717, 0.00755638734840589)), row.names = c(NA, -11L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has functions which do loops for you, including base `lapply()` 
In this case, there is a `purrr::map` version of `lapply` to output a dataframe instead of a list,  `map_df()`, which does the work of combining into one dataframe for you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df <-
  structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1479118194, 1479116870, 
                                         1479113506, 1479113046, 1479112331, 1479111645, 1479111119, 1479110437, 
                                         1479106612, 1479106218, 1479105192), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                                         ), tzone = "UTC"), heading = c(44L, 72L, 37L, 34L, 14L, 12L, 
                                                                        15L, 13L, 45L, 14L, 16L), ground.speed1 = c(0.0830056886417697, 
                                                                                                                    0.0362715909791526, 0.373922822992792, 0.00365221791296628, 0.0486211951021842, 
                                                                                                                    0.181217669168713, 0.0550965979273319, 0.154570465194361, 1.55730089114108, 
                                                                                                                    0.259570141800717, 0.00755638734840589)), row.names = c(NA, -11L
                                                                                                                    ), class = "data.frame")

yrs <- 2:-30  # create the yrs to loop over
map_df(yrs,   # repeats the command for each element in yrs
       ~mutate(df, 
               timestamp = timestamp-years(.x), # use .x wherever you would use "i" in a loop
               changes= paste0(.x, "y")))

#>               timestamp heading ground.speed1 changes
#> 1   2015-11-14 10:09:54      44   0.083005689      1y
#> 2   2015-11-14 09:47:50      72   0.036271591      1y
#> 3   2015-11-14 08:51:46      37   0.373922823      1y
#> 4   2015-11-14 08:44:06      34   0.003652218      1y
#> ...
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>